# How to display Vuex state reactively (change what's displayed when the state change)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, state-management

I have Vue.js project with Vuex. In my Vuex store, I have state named *page*.
This is my index.js in store folder:

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex"

export default createStore({
    state () {
        return {
            page: 'page-one'
        }
    },

    mutations: {
        changePage(state, page) {
            state.page = page
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getCurrentPage(state) {
            return state.page
        }
    }
})
```

I have few buttons that change the *page* state to different string.

```html
<li class="app-section-link" @click="setPageTo('page-one')">1</li>
<li class="app-section-link" @click="setPageTo('page-two')">2</li>
<li class="app-section-link" @click="setPageTo('page-three')">3</li>
```

These buttons are inside component with this method:

```js
export default {
    name: 'PageChanger',

    methods: {
        setPageTo: function(page) {
            this.$store.commit('changePage', page)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have this component:

```html
<template>
    <div class="main-app">
        {{ currentPage }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'MainApp',
    computed: {
        currentPage() {
            return this.$store.getters.getCurrentPage
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When I load the app, it displays *page-one* inside *main-app* div, but when I click the buttons, it doesn't change. In Vue DevTools, I see the *page* state changes when I click the buttons, but displayed text is still *page-one*.

I tried the above code, I expected the text to change everytime I change the *page* state, but when I change the state, the text doesn't change.

Comment: There's no getCurrentPage in the code you provided. If it really exists then it should work, please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. See See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry it's there I just forgot to paste it, I edited it.

Comment: What you have should work. Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve] reproducing the bug? Consider using codesandbox.io.

Comment: I did it, but it now works, so I must have different bug in my code somewhere

Answer (score 0):

## **I figured it out!**

When creating my project, I followed some random tutorial.
In the tutorial, I installed Vuex manually with npm, but it didn't add it to the package.json file.

Now I added Vuex here manually:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vuex": "4.1.0"
  },
```

I run *npm install* and *npm run serve* again...
and it works perfectly.

Comment: In this case, it's quite strange the page initially showed `page-one`. You should have at least seen some message about the store not being able to find `vuex` and import `createStore` from it.

Comment: It is strange, but it was just like that.